# Tomcat Eden overuse

Tags: tomcat, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a Tomcat running an app.
I had some memory issues and I was able to to tune the Tomcat after few attempts so it won't collapse, but while looking at the Tomcat manager, I noticed that I use the entire eden space in like 5 sec.
Is it 'normal' or I'm at a break of another collapse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eden Space is part of the Young Generation, which means you get a minor GC every 5 seconds. Depending on your heap size a minor GC pause should only last a few milliseconds. A few hundred tops.

So the JVM is only spending a tiny fraction of its CPU time on GCing. So yes, that's fine.

For a more detailed analysis GC logs and configuration would be needed.